# iOS (Swift) application is crashing on JSON parsing

Tags: ios, swift, string, crash

I am calling rest api in iOS (Swift) application and getting response in JSON. But when I am trying to parse it then application is crashing on this line

```
let myData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
```

**Code:**

```
print("JSON Response String: \(String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))")

var jsonString:String = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!

jsonString = jsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") 

let myData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)                            

let dict:[String:Any] = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData!, options: []) as? [String:Any])!

print("JSON Response Dictionary: \(dict)")
```

**Crash log**

> JSON Response String: Optional("{\n  \"ConsumerID\":
>   \"w4wccKqF9qN0biUM3HGvGMDK27Q2\", \n  \"resultCount\": 10, \n 
>   \"resultList\": [\n    \"Thai Basil\", \n    \"Thai Pineapple Curry\",
>   \n    \"Thai Lettuce Wrap\", \n    \"Thai Green Curry\", \n    \"Thai
>   Red Curry\", \n    \"Thai String Bean Shrimp\", \n    \"Thai Basil
>   Eggplant\", \n    \"Thai Basil Drunken Noodle \\"Pad Kee Mao\\"\",
>   \n    \"Thai Chili Fish\", \n    \"1. Thai Egg Roll(3)\"\n  ]\n}\n")

**Crash log:**

> caught: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed array
>   around character 305." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed array
>   around character 305.}

Comment: it's because array in response is posted like string

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because fo this line of code:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

you have to use the correct escape characters accordingly:

The following characters are reserved in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings:

```
Backspace is replaced with \b
Form feed is replaced with \f
Newline is replaced with \n
Carriage return is replaced with \r
Tab is replaced with \t
Double quote is replaced with \"
Backslash is replaced with \\
```

So the correct way would be:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "\\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json response log, your backend seem to be returning an invalid json response. Below should be the correct json response.

```
{  
   "ConsumerID":"w4wccKqF9qN0biUM3HGvGMDK27Q2",
   "resultCount":10,
   "resultList":[  
      "Thai Basil",
      "Thai Pineapple Curry",
      "Thai Lettuce Wrap",
      "Thai Green Curry",
      "Thai Red Curry",
      "Thai String Bean Shrimp",
      "Thai Basil Eggplant",
      "Thai Basil Drunken Noodle \"Pad Kee Mao\"",
      "Thai Chili Fish",
      "1. Thai Egg Roll(3)"
   ]
}
```